# Flowchart with CSS/HTML

Tags: html, css, rounded-corners, flowchart, html-heading

Currently I'm trying to make a flowchart, this is the code I've got so far:

```css
 #flowchart {
        width: 580px; 
        text-align: center;
        font-family: sans-serif;
        font-size: .8em;
        margin: auto;
    }  
    #flowchart a {
        display: block;
        color: white;
        text-decoration: none;
        background-color: #2F41B1;
        padding: 2em 1em;
    }
    #flowchart a:hover {
        color: #111;
        background-color: #EFA707;
    }
    .no1 {
        width: 390px;
        border: 1px solid #444;
        margin: 0 auto;
    }
    .line1 {
        width: 1px;
        height: 20px;
        background-color: #000;
        margin: 0 auto;
    } 
    .clear {
        clear:both;
    }
```

```html
    <div id="flowchart">
        <div class="no1"><a href="http://example.com/page1">Step 1:
    Blah blah blah, do this.</a></div>
        <div class="line1"></div>
        <div class="no1"><a href="http://example.com/page2">Step 2: 
    Then this and that.</a></div>
        <div class="line1"></div>
        <div class="no1"><a href="example.com/page3">Step 3: 
    Now finally go here and there.</a></div>
    
    </div>​
```

How can I make only the headings ("step x") for each section be bold and larger? (and not the content after, "blah blah then this etc")

Also, how can I make rounded corners instead of sharp edges?

Comment: 1. font-weight:bold; and font-size:2em;   2.border-radius:3px;

Comment: Thanks Sven, but I only want the headings and not the rest of the text to be changed (I tweaked what I posted to make that clearer).

If it was all the text I wanted the change to be done to I know enough to do that myself :-P :-P

Comment: then put the text you want explicitly changed in a span with a class and attach the styles to that class

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make the *Step x* styled differently, you need to wrap it in a `<span class="flowchartHeader">...</span>` tag, then add this to your CSS:

```
.flowchartHeader {
    font-size: 1.2em;
    font-weight: bold;
}
```

As for rounding, add `border-radius: 6px` to `.no1`.

Comment: Unfortunately I could only pick one as an answer, but I picked this one as it is was the most "complete" answer because it answered both parts of my question. Thanks! I'm once again very impressed by the community at Stackoverflow :-D

Answer (score 2):

i made a quick fiddle of what you wand dude. http://jsfiddle.net/jalbertbowdenii/NY973/1/

Comment: Cheers! As yours was posted first is what I've been using :-P
However, now I see the other replies I've got one more question....

Why do you have this extra portion that the others haven't suggested:
-webkit-border-radius: 5px;
-moz-border-radius:5px; -ms-border-radius:5px; -0-border-radius:5px;

Comment: that covers all browsers that only support vendor prefixes; the last one, border-radius by itself, is just the fallback. it covers you're bases in more browsers

Comment: `-webkit`, `-moz`, and `-o` are prefixes specific to Chrome/Safari, Firefox, and Opera, respectively.  They implemented these features before the CSS specification added in the attribute (which is listed without the prefix). The most recent version of all those browsers and IE support the border-radius attribute, but older versions may or may not support it without the prefixed version.

Answer (score 0):

Use this to generate the round corners css for you [border-radius.com](http://border-radius.com/)

```
.myClass{

-webkit-border-radius: 50px;
-moz-border-radius: 50px;
border-radius: 50px;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 .no1
    {
        width: 390px;
        border: 1px solid #444;
        margin: 0 auto;
        border-radius:5px;  //add this
    }
```